# CakePHP: Random query with one result, exclude two values

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I try to exclude two values on a random query, but it gets ignored. Maybe one of you can enlighten me. This is my code:

```php
$random = $this->Gerde
    ->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'OR' => [
                'NOT' => [
                    ['employees' => 'BLUE'],
                    ['employees' => 'RED']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->order('rand()')
    ->first();
```

I get my single random result but red and blue employees appear anyway. Does my logic suck? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the two values to be excluded in the final results you get everytime?

Comment: I get single random results as wished. But sometimes unwanted results appear.

Comment: Would `'conditions' => ['employees NOT IN' => ['BLUE', 'RED']]` work?

Comment: Thank you very much! Will put your answer to my archive for further instance. Meanwhile I came across another solution. Will test it and report...
['conditions' => ['NOT' => [['employees' => 'BLUE'],['employees' => 'RED']]  ] ]

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you, mine was bad. Your solution works wonderful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GregSchmidts answer was the right one.
My code looks like this now and works like a charme:

```
$random = $this->Gerde->find('all', ['conditions' => ['employees NOT IN' => ['BLUE','RED'] ] ])
                         ->order('rand()')
                         ->first();
```